# xslt transformation to return attributes with specified prefix

Tags: xml, xslt

Below are my xml and xslt strings..

```
 xml='<SampleXML>
        <header>
            <Id>123</Id>
        </header>
        <properties>
            <property name="a1_name1" value="apple"/>
            <property name="a1_name2" value="SALE"/>
            <property name="a2_name3" value="20130425"/>
        </properties>

    </SampleXML>


';

xslt ="<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">
    <xsl:template match=\"SampleXML/header\"/>  
    <xsl:template match=\"SampleXML/properties\">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=\"property[position() = 1]\">
            <xsl:with-param name=\"mode\">name</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>;<xsl:apply-templates select=\"property[position() = 1]\">
            <xsl:with-param name=\"mode\">value</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>~</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=\"property\">
    <xsl:param name=\"mode\" />
    <xsl:if test=\"$mode='name'\">
        <xsl:variable name=\"sub\"><xsl:apply-templates select=\"following-sibling::*[1]\"><xsl:with-param name=\"mode\" select=\"$mode\"/></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select=\"@name\"/>|<xsl:value-of select=\"$sub\"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=\"$mode='value'\">
        <xsl:variable name=\"sub\"><xsl:apply-templates select=\"following-sibling::*[1]\"><xsl:with-param name=\"mode\" select=\"$mode\"/></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select=\"@value\"/>|<xsl:value-of select=\"$sub\"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>";
```

This gives me an output of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
a1_name1|a1_name2|a2_name3|;apple|SALE|20130425|~
```

How to modify the xslt to see in the output only those with prefix 'a1'.Something like below..Tried using the template matching but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
a1_name1|a1_name2;apple|SALE~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="SampleXML/header"/>
    <xsl:template match="SampleXML/properties">
        <xsl:for-each select="property[starts-with(@name,'a1')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:if test ="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="property[starts-with(@name,'a1')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            <xsl:if test ="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate:

```
   a1_name1|a1_name2;apple|SALE~
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, if you want to exclude **property** elements whose **name** attributes begin with 'a1' just add the following template to ignore then

```
<xsl:template match="property[not(starts-with(@name, 'a1_'))]" />
```

Note how this template is closed off immediately, and so is empty. It other words it does nothing. When it matches a property element whose name attribute doesn't start with 'a1_' nothing will be output.

The XSLT processor will match the most specific template first, so this one will take priority to ignore the elements.

However, it might be worth noting you can probably simplify your current XSLT a bit. You are currently passing a **mode** attribute, to determine which attribute to output. Another way of doing this would be as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:param name="mode"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $mode]"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Note there is not need to call **xsl:apply-templates** one element at a time, just select them all in a single statement.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="property">
   <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'name'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

They will be selected in order, so it won't be an issue. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="SampleXML/header"/>

   <xsl:template match="SampleXML/properties">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="property">
         <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'name'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="property">
         <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'value'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="property[not(starts-with(@name, 'a1_'))]"/>

   <xsl:template match="property">
      <xsl:param name="mode"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $mode]"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
a1_name1|a1_name2|;apple|SALE|~
```

Comment: im confused .Why is it outputting those that start with a1 when you are asking it not to display them..If i try the other way round <xsl:template match="property[starts-with(@name, 'a1_')]"/>, it is giving me a2_name3|;20130425|~ ..Why is this happening?

Comment: I've amended by question to explain but. It is because the template `<xsl:template match="property[starts-with(@name, 'a1_')]"/>` matches **property** elements whose name starts with 'a1_'. But the template is empty. There is no code with the template, and so when it matches an element it does nothing, and so the element does not get output.